# Create a finalizeBy with parameters in gradle

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to make a finalized by in a gradle where there is parameters?

I want to do something like below in a gradle file:

```
task mytask() {
    group = "my-group"
    finalizedBy('some-other-task -pParam=SOME-VALUE')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not possible.**

---

The reason is quite simple: In Gradle, every task will run at most once during a build. Now if two tasks would depend on (or be finalized by) the same task, but using other parameters, there would be no way to decide how to execute the task as it cannot be executed twice:

```
task a {
    dependsOn 'b', 'c'
}

task b {
    finalizedBy('d -Pparam=foo')
}

task c {
    finalizedBy('d -Pparam=bar')
}

task d {
    // do something
}
```

What should happen when you call `gradle a`?

However, you can configure a task during the execution of another task, which may solve your problem:

```
task mytask {
    group = "my-group"
    finalizedBy 'someOtherTask'
    doLast {
        someOtherTask.param = value
    }
}
```

This way, `someOtherTask` will use `value` for `param` when it is run after `mytask`, but not if it is called directly using `gradle someOtherTask`.